# Is it possible to run Mule 2.2.1 on spring 3?

Tags: spring, spring-security, mule, spring-3

We have an application that is currently running spring 2.5.6 and mule 2.2.1. We have decided to go ahead and upgrade the app to use spring 3.2 we also upgraded spring security to 3.1. I understand that Mule 2.2.1 uses spring 2.5.6 for configuration and so forth. We were to re-factor our code and build the entire project. However after deploying the application and starting the server, my server started in about 6 seconds instead of the normal 30 seconds and then I noticed that none of my services were not loaded. Unfortunately after days of investigating I cannot find where everything fails, as there are no errors in any of the logs including spring and mule logs. My question is it possible to get these to play together or should I just forget about getting this to work.

I read this post http://lifeinide.blogspot.com/2012/07/spring-3-and-mule-2-initialized-by.html and followed these instruction and still was not able to get it work. Mule says it started up just fine without any errors but I can hit any of my services. Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @genjosanzo for the pointer. It helped met dig into this issue better and eventually make it work.

@mtanzania,
We had a similar need like yours - need to make Mule 2.2.1 work with Spring 3.2.x releases. Upgrade to Mule 3 involved rewrite of Mule extensions such as exception handling strategies, a RabbitMQ Mule transport etc. Upgrade to Mule 3 was therefore ruled out.
In order to make this work, you need to rewrite/update 3 java files from your module:

```
groupId:org.mule.modules
artifactId:mule-module-spring-config
version:2.2.1
```

with implementations from :

```
groupId:org.mule.modules
artifactId:mule-module-spring-config
version:3.4.0
```

To be more specific, you need these classes to be updated/upgraded: MuleBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java, MuleApplicationContext.java and SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java

With these updated versions, you can continue to create the MuleContext like:

```
SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder springConfigBuilder = new   SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder(muleConfigPaths);
MuleContext context = new DefaultMuleContextFactory().createMuleContext(springConfigBuilder)
```

The modified implementations are here : [Mule in Trooper](https://github.com/regunathb/Trooper/tree/master/serviceframework-seda/src/main/java/org/trpr/platform/seda/impl/mule/spring) and sample class that uses this is here : [Trooper Mule container](https://github.com/regunathb/Trooper/blob/master/serviceframework-seda/src/main/java/org/trpr/platform/seda/impl/service/MuleServicesContainer.java)

Answer (score 0):

Mule uses some internal spring API to parse the mule configuration and creates the correspondent beans.

For this reason the upgrade might work with spring 3.0.x but I'm pretty sure that something got broken with spring 3.1.x (i.e. [this code](https://fisheye.codehaus.org/changelog/mule/?cs=23617) has been introduced to maintain backward compatibility).

How about upgrading mule as well? Most of the 2.2.x syntax is still supported and many new feature has been introduced in newer mule versions.

Comment: Thanks genjosanzo, we tried to upgrade mule also at the same but we also have dependencies on jbpm 3 while mule 3 uses jbpm4, and upgrading jbpm is currently not an option for us, as it is way too much to tackle than the resources we have available and also after a little online research there seems to be some concerns with the future of jbpm4 as redhat won't support, (I am not sure how true these claims are but there are enough concerns out there for us to be concerned). Thank you again for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, the above answer from @regunathb is right on. Patching in those three classes works. However, it is important to note that the 3.4 version of those classes from mule-module-spring-config will **not** work as-is. You **must** get the modified versions of the classes that @regunathb posted on GitHub, otherwise you'll end up with various incompatibilities between 3.4 and 2.2.1.